# Cocoa - Change text of label

Tags: cocoa

I've got a cocoa application that reads in a text file.  I'd like to display that text in a multi-line label, but I for the life of me can't figure it out.  I opened up my .nib file and poped a multi-line label down but after that I'm stuck.

I don't have any experience working with Xcode or Cocoa, mostly Eclipse, Visual Studio, and pretty much every other IDE except Xcode which seems very foreign.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have the text in an NSString, you can easily put it in the label.

First, in the .h file (or header) of your controller class, create a new IBOutlet so you can refer to the label:

`IBOutlet NSTextField *myLabel;`

Go into the .xib file where the label is. Control-drag from the controller object to the label, and select the "myLabel" option to apply it to that specific label.

Then, in the method where you want to put the text in the label, type the following:

`[myLabel setStringValue:myString];` (where "myString" is your NSString)

Note: This is all assuming you know how to do basic things like controller classes- if not, I'd definitely check out Cocoa Dev Central (http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/.)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know about controller classes

Comment: Nick: You (should) have an object that owns the window and all its views, and also the model (at least part of that model being the value you want to display in the label). That object is a controller. The controller class golfromeo is referring to is simply the class of that object. For more info, see the Cocoa Fundamentals Guide: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/